# Как сменить кодировку UTF-8 в cmd windows?

Tags: python-3.x, консоль, utf-8, windows-7

Файл должен выводиться в utf-8, а в консоли - 866, в итоге, в браузере отображаются ромбы.

После команды `chcp 65001` ничего не поменялось.

Поскольку в консоли используется кодовая страница 866, то если в реестре поменять значение `REG_SZ`-параметра "866" под ключом `[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]` с "C_866.nls" (по умолчанию) на иное, то и кодировка в cmd также должна измениться.

Но у меня в CodePage таких файлов нет. Есть типы `REG.SZ` по умолчанию и 4 файла с номерами 932 936 949 950.

Вариант постоянно изменять в консоли chcp не подходит, но и не работает. Lucida console подключен в консоли.
Cygwin64 Terminal и Gitbash не запускает python server

Какие-то ещё есть варианты?

generate_all.py

```html
# coding: utf-8

from horoscope import generate_prophecies
from datetime import datetime as dt


def generate_page(head, body):
    page = f"<html>{head}{body}</html>"
    return page


def generate_head(title):
    head = f"""<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    """
    return head


def generate_body(header, paragraphs):
    body = f"<h1>{header}</h1>"
    for p in paragraphs:
        body = body + f"<p>{p}</p>"
    return f"<body>{body}</body>"


def save_page(title, header, paragraphs, output="index.html"):
    fp = open(output, "w")
    today = dt.now().date()
    page = generate_page(
        head=generate_head(title),
        body=generate_body(header=header, paragraphs=paragraphs)
    )
    print(page, file=fp)
    fp.close()

#####################


today = dt.now().date()

save_page(
    title="Гороскоп на сегодня",
    header="Что день " + str(today) + " готовит",
    paragraphs=generate_prophecies(),
)
```

horoscope.py

```html
import random
times = ['утром', 'днем', 'вечером', 'ночью', 'после обеда', 'перед сном']
advices = ['ожидайте', 'предостерегайтесь', 'будьте открыты для']
promises = ['гостей из забытого прошлого', 'встреч со старыми знакомыми',
            'неожиданного праздника', 'приятных перемен']

def generate_prophecies(total_num=5, num_sentences=3):
    prophecies = []
    for i in range(total_num):
        forecast = ''
        for j in range(num_sentences):
            t = random.choice(times)
            a = random.choice(advices)
            p = random.choice(promises)
            full_sentence = f'{t.title()} {a} {p}.'
            if j != num_sentences - 1:
                full_sentence = full_sentence + ' '
    forecast = forecast + full_sentence
    prophecies.append(forecast)
    return prophecies
```

При запуске кода через powershell и сервера в этой же директории python -m http.server) из консоли win  (`python generate_all.py` из командной строки или Ctrl+B в
саблайме)  в этой же папке генерируется файл `index.html`, и в браузере можно увидеть ромбы.

Все файлы в utf-8,

Comment: все смешалось люди, кони. тут вам и консоль и тут же браузер. чего надо то?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window  Все свои проекты веду в utf-8. Несколько раз приходилось запускать в командной строке. Команда `chcp 65001` каждый раз работала. Что я делаю не так?! В настоящее время пользуюсь `bash` от git'a

Comment: @ ArchDemon Код написан в python c кодировкой utf-8, в консоли win- 866 Bash не запускает сервер

Comment: @ ArchDemon скрипт  bash даже powershell не запускает. а на команде python-m http.server 8080 - просто зависает.

Comment: А вы уверены, что причина в кодировке? Вы уверены что проблема вообще есть. И это не зависание, а активная работа? То что вы видите ромбы в браузере, может говорить о том, что у вас не указана кодировка страницы через тег `<meta>`

Comment: @  ArchDemon Какие теги <мета> в питоне? У меня указана кодировка # coding: utf-8 в general_all.py  Можете сгенерировать и посмотреть эти 2 файла. Это проблема консоли именно win 7

Comment: Вы говорите что в браузере ромбы. Я указал откуда так может быть. То что у вас написано  `# coding: utf-8` вовсе не говорит о кодировке файла. Я такой текст могу в любой текстовый файл написать c кодировкой ASCII. Советую вам взять какой-нибудь Notepad++ и посмотреть кодировку файла. В случае необходимости сконвертировать в нужную

Comment: @ ArchDemon вручную конвертировать сгенерированный index.html не вариант, а файлы .py итак в кодировке utf-8, редактор это показывает. Более того, даже index.html в браузере в utf-8 Это отображает Charset Detective Но я нашел простое решение.